# Ruby refactoring: converting array to hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here's what I get in Rails params:

```
obj => {
    "raw_data" =>
        [
            { "id" => "1", "name" => "John Doe" },
            { "id" => "2", "name" => "Jane Doe" }
        ]
}
```

I have to transform into a following object:

```
obj => {
    "data" =>
        {
            "1" => { "name" => "John Doe" },
            "2" => { "name" => "Jane Doe" }
        }
}
```

Here's the code I have working so far:

```
if obj[:raw_data]
    obj[:data] = Hash.new
    obj[:raw_data].each do |raw|
      obj[:data][raw[:id]] = Hash.new
      obj[:data][raw[:id]][:name] = raw[:name] if raw[:name].present?
    end
end
obj.delete(:raw_data)
```

Is there a way to refactor it? Maybe using `map`. Note that data structure has to change from array to hash as well.

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
obj = {
  "raw_data" => [
    { "id" => "1", "name" => "John Doe" },
    { "id" => "2", "name" => "Jane Doe" }
  ]
}

data = obj["raw_data"].map do |item|
  item = item.dup
  [ item.delete('id'), item ]
end

obj2 = { "data" => data.to_h }
# => { "data" =>
#      { "1" => { "name" => "John Doe" },
#        "2" => { "name" => "Jane Doe" }
#      }
#    }
```

If you're using Rails you can use the [`Hash#except`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-except) method from ActiveSupport to make it a little more succinct:

```
data = obj["raw_data"].map {|item| [ item["id"], item.except("id") ] }
obj2 = { "data" => data.to_h }
```

Comment: You are relying on the order of the array being the same as the id's which is a faulty assumption. `[ { "id" => 5, "name" => "John Doe" } , { "id" => 15, "name" => "Jane Doe" } ] ` would give the wrong output.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood how this code works. The [output](http://ideone.com/qKMZ6c) it gives for that input is `{ 5 => { "name" => "John Doe" }, 15 => { "name" => "Jane Doe" } }`. What output do you think it should give?

Comment: Ah, you're correct, missed the `[ item.delete('id'), item ]` part. Sorry

Comment: Perfect, thanks Jordan, I used the one with except. Short and sweet :)

Answer (score 1):

```
d = obj[:raw_data]
keys = d.map { |h| h["id"] }
values = d.map { |h| h.except("id") }
Hash[ keys.zip(values) ]

# or as a oneliner
Hash[ d.map { |h| h["id"] }.zip(d.map { |h| h.except("id")) ]
# => {"1"=>{"name"=>"John Doe"}, "2"=>{"name"=>"Jane Doe"}}
```

This special [`Hash[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) syntax lets you create a hash from a array of keys and an array of values.

`Hash.except(*args)` is an ActiveSupport addition to the hash class which returns a new key without the keys in the blacklist.

Comment: Why don't we have [Hash#except](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-except) in pure-Ruby? Does this have a counterpart `include_only` (to avoid the need for `h.except(*(h.keys-include_keys))`)?

Comment: Kitesurfing instructor? Decided to go for the big money, eh?

Comment: The inverse of `Hash#except` is `Hash#slice` which takes a whitelist instead of a blacklist, would be nice to have them in the stdlib. @CarySwoveland

Comment: There are other things to life than money :) @CarySwoveland

Answer (score 0):

In rails, you can use `index_by` method:

```
obj = {raw_data: [{id: "1", name: "John Doe"}, {id: "2", name: "Jane Doe"}]}

obj2 = {
 data: obj[:raw_data].index_by {|h| h[:id]}.each {|_,h| h.delete(:id)}
} #=> {:data=>{"1"=>{:name=>"John Doe"}, "2"=>{:name=>"Jane Doe"}}}
```

One downfall of this is that it will modify the original data by deleting id property. If this is unacceptable, here is modified, safe version:

```
obj2 = {
 data: obj[:raw_data].map(&:clone).index_by {|h| h[:id]}.each {|_,h| h.delete(:id)}
} #=> {:data=>{"1"=>{:name=>"John Doe"}, "2"=>{:name=>"Jane Doe"}}}
```

Comment: This has the undesirable side effect of altering the original hash.

Comment: @max - True to that, up to OP to decide whether this is a fair trade-off for code simplicity in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean `obj = {...}` and not `obj => {...}`, as the latter is not a valid object. If so:

```
{ "data" => obj["raw_data"].each_with_object({}) { |g,h|
  h[g["id"]] = g.reject { |k,_| k == "id" } } }
  #=> {"data"=>{"1"=>{"name"=>"John Doe"}, "2"=>{"name"=>"Jane Doe"}}}
```

If `obj` can be mutated, you can simplify a bit:

```
{ "data" => obj["raw_data"].each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[g.delete("id")]=g } }
```

As an improved non-mutating solution, @Max suggested a Rails' tweak:

```
{ "data" => obj["raw_data"].each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[g["id"]] = g.except("id") } }
```

That looks good to me, but as I don't know rails, I'm taking that advice at face value.

Comment: I like it, in rails you might want to use `h[g['id']] = g.except(:id)` as its both succinct and side effect free.